# CSS3 Loading Circle

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a CSS3 Circle Loader that has 3 circles. I am having problems Each circle (starting from the first) should fade out after a few seconds possibly using CSS Animations. Any help is appreciated.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/8kQ2u/1/)

Comment: If there is no any important reason to use css in this task. I suggest to use loading images generated at http://chimply.com .

Comment: Why aren't you just using an animated gif for this?

Comment: @BillyMoat , Gifs are easier but it is possible in CSS3 and loads faster.

Comment: I'm all for using css instead of images if it represents a real world value for download speed etc. However a gif for this will only be a few kilobytes at most so I'm not sure the effort of making a css solution for it (which will be css3 only so won't work in older browsers) is much use. Use the gif Luke (James).

Comment: @BillyMoat The only reason I can think of using CSS instead of GIF is that it _is easier to do, mantain and review_. I'd be nice if we could _render_ our finished CSS solution to a GIF, don't you think?

Comment: I've made a [bit fancier](http://jsfiddle.net/Nux3z/2/) version of the loader circles.

Comment: @jmendeth I would argue that SVG is easier to maintain than a GIF (particularly if you're wanting to customize the colors), but I don't see that suggested too often!

Comment: @cimmanon I agree that for these things, SVG is better than CSS. But what about animation? GIF makes it possible. Also GIF has better support than CSS or SVG based solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go a slightly different route.
Only made for webkit but you can alter as needed: http://jsfiddle.net/8kQ2u/17/

```
@-webkit-keyframes fades {
    0%, 100% { 
       opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
       opacity: 0;
    }
}

.circle span  {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 9.975em auto;
  background: #dbdbdb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -ms-border-radius: 50px;
  -o-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fades;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.circle span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.circle span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
​
```

`:nth-child` here is fine since I'm pretty sure it has full support in browsers that support `@keyframes`. You could use the sibling selector if you prefered (`+`).

Comment: `-o-border-radius`? What an ugly prefixer you are using! I think that non-prefixed properties only is totally fine for SO answer.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Except for things like `animation`, which are *not* supported without prefix [yet].

Comment: Your solution is fine, except the animation is not clear enough to be noticed.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov you should probably check the OP post before commenting on syntax. I only added the animation declarations.

Comment: @sємsєм glad its working for you. Thought you just wanted to fade the icons out which is why I went with that, easy enough change though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use of keyframes will do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Nux3z/

Couple of details:

```
1) Use of :nth-child, or :first-child, etc to target your elements
2) Timing of animations: I'm using 1.7, 2.7, rather than 0.7s, 1.4s because I'm allowing for the 1s of fade to finish NOT simply doubling/tripling the time each element takes to animate.
3) Not a solution for IE
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, using *animations* and *timing* is essencial here.
In fact, each circle is used **the same animation**,
but you must apply a different **delay** to each circle.

See below (I'm also using `nth-child` instead of `first-child`):

```
.circle span {
    /** The same animation to each circle **/
    -webkit-animation: circleFade 3s linear infinite;
}

/** Different animation delays **/
.circle span:nth-child(1) { -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; }
.circle span:nth-child(2) { -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; }
.circle span:nth-child(3) { -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; }

/** Animation **/
@-webkit-keyframes circleFade {
     0% { background: #ddd; }
    25% { background: #999; }
    35% { background: #999; }
    60% { background: #ddd; }
}​
```

[[See the fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/Nux3z/1/)
[[Now see the *fancy* fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/Nux3z/2/)